# ActiveMQ fails to create local registry when started from Maven in console

Tags: java, maven, jms, activemq-classic

I am having trouble initializing ActiveMQ (activemq-core:5.7.0) when running the unit test with maven from console. Everything is working fine when I run it from Intellij.

Result from Intellij runner:

```
2016-07-04 14:21:22 DEBUG JNDIHelper:90 - {java.naming.provider.url=vm://localhost, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, java.naming.security.authentication=true}
2016-07-04 14:21:22 DEBUG ManagementContext:492 - Creating RMIRegistry on port 1099
2016-07-04 14:21:22 DEBUG ManagementContext:507 - Probably not using JRE 1.4: mx4j.tools.naming.NamingService
2016-07-04 14:21:22 DEBUG ManagementContext:522 - Created JMXConnectorServer javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer@52ac6ca7
2016-07-04 14:21:22 DEBUG ManagementContext:120 - Starting JMXConnectorServer...
```

Result from mvn test:

```
2016-07-04 14:00:26 DEBUG JNDIHelper:90 - {java.naming.provider.url=vm://localhost, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, java.naming.security.authentication=true}
2016-07-04 14:00:26 DEBUG ManagementContext:509 - Failed to create local registry. This exception will be ignored.
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
            at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:223)
            at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.createConnector(ManagementContext.java:492)
            at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.findTigerMBeanServer(ManagementContext.java:4
    ...
    2016-07-04 14:35:16 ERROR ManagementContext:423 - Failed to initialize MBeanServer
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    ...
    2016-07-04 14:35:16 DEBUG ManagementContext:107 - Error invoking start on mbean null. This exception is ignored.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.start(ManagementContext.java:102)
            at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startManagementContext(BrokerService.java:2367)
    ...
```

Infrastructure which I am using:

```
<infrastructure name="localhost" host="vm://localhost"
                        port="0" channel="" connectionType="JNDI" connectionFactory="ConnectionFactory"
                        contextFactory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
                        reconnectInterval="30" reconnectIntervalTimeUnit="SECONDS"
                        reconnectAttempts="30" />
```

Comment: Looks like you have a wrong Version of slf4j. Try to use the correct one and the logmessage can help to find out what is happend

Comment: I have added the slf4j dependency and now the test passes even though the errors are the same.. Very weird.